# VueJs Mulitple Component Instances - Performance Impact

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This question is related to understanding how Vue handles component instances.

I have a 'smart text area' this text area component has many methods within for highlighting text, regex matching and updating the text area changes in the backend. So it's a relatively complex component. The user can create and unlimited number of these components.

What i'm struggling to understand is, does Vue create a brand new instance of these components every time or does it re use the same component code in the same way we use regular functions?

My concern is that if a user creates 1000 text areas we now have 1000 instances of all of the heavy methods used in each component. This could lead to serious performance issues.

Is this the correct understanding of how these components work?

Comment: What kind of form would need 1000 text areas?!  Talk about a UX nightmare.  I know this doesn't answer your question (that's why it's a comment) but you may want keep track of the component count and limit it to a reasonable amount.

Comment: so its not really a form. Each of these components represents a message box. Imagine a watsapp chat. But the idea is that you can scroll through and edit those messages which is where the inner methods come in. Good point on limiting i'm just curious how vue handles these in the background